How to find the highest clocked CPU core under linux in bash?
I wonder what clock speed my CPU cores are boosting to. How do I find out under Linux in BASH?
In today's dynamically boosting CPUs, the clock speed depends on the current workload. Modern games for example are relatively multithreaded, using 6 or 8 cores is common in AAA titles. When I can decide if I use more cores in my own applications, I need to consider how much single-core clock speed I am trading for the extra parallelism.
I can produce arbitrarily multithreaded CPU load like so:
stress-ng --cpu 1

There is information about the CPU clock in sysfs:
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 23
model       : 1
model name  : AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X 16-Core Processor
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x8001137
cpu MHz     : 2200.000
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 16
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 16
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid amd_dcm aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate ssbd ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca sev
bugs        : sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass retbleed smt_rsb srso div0
bogomips    : 6799.35
TLB size    : 2560 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm hwpstate eff_freq_ro [13] [14]
[...]


Please [edit] your question and add your desired output.

On some recent CPUs, there's one core capable of higher turbo clocks than the others.  ("Golden core").  When the vendor tests the silicon, they identify which core on the chip is the coolest-running and stable at a higher clock speed than the others, and burn that info into the silicon (with fuses built into the design for that purpose, I assume).

Monitoring cpu frequencies:
Preamble: getCpuFreqs
In order to reduce system footprint, as we plan to do this operation repetitively and very quickly, I've replaced sed -ne '/^cpu .Hz/s/.*: //p' < /proc/cpuinfo | sort -rn by the following function, without forks and without loop:
getCpuFreqs() {
    local _cF__str _cpuInf
    mapfile -t _cpuInf < /proc/cpuinfo
    _cpuInf=(${_cpuInf[@]/#!(cpu MHz+($'\t'): *)})
    printf -v _cF__str '[9999999999999999-%s]+="%%s " ' ${_cpuInf[@]/.}
    printf -v _cF__str "$_cF__str" ${_cpuInf[@]}
    local -i _cF__i _cF__l _cF__r
    local -a _cpuInf="($_cF__str)"
    IFS=\  read -ra "${1:-cpuFreqs}" <<<"${_cpuInf[*]}"
}

To avoid forks, this function will populate a variable instead of printing his result out. So I could replace:

        mapfile -t freqs < <(
            sed -ne '/^cpu .Hz/s/.*: //p' < /proc/cpuinfo |
                sort -rn
        )


by:
        getCpuFreqs freqs

in following function.
The CPU Frequency monitor
As a function:
monitCpuFreq() {
    local top=0 lowest freqs init bgcolor delay=${1:-0.1} strtop nl
    local -i cRose=217 cPeach=209 cBrYellow=229 cBrGreen=151 cPaleBlue=110 i
    while ! read -sn 1 -t $delay _; do
        getCpuFreqs freqs
        (( ${freqs[0]/.} > ${top/.} )) && top=${freqs[0]}
        ! [[ $lowest ]] || (( ${freqs[-1]/.} < ${lowest/.} )) &&
            lowest=${freqs[-1]}
        if ! [[ -n $init ]]; then
            printf '%.0s\n' ${freqs[@]:1}
            printf '\e[%dA\e7' $(( ${#freqs[@]} -1 ))
            init='done'
        fi
        printf '\e8'
        printf -v strtop 'Top:    %8.3f Mhz' $top
        for i in ${!freqs[@]}; do
            (( i == ${#freqs[@]} -1 )) && nl=\\r || nl=\\n
            bgcolor=$(( ${freqs[i]/.*} >= 3675 ? cRose :
                        ${freqs[i]/.*} >= 3275 ? cPeach :
                        ${freqs[i]/.*} >= 2175 ? cBrYellow :
                        ${freqs[i]/.*} >= 1975 ? cBrGreen : cPaleBlue ))
            printf '\e[48;5;%dm\e[30m%s MHz\e[0m \r\e[16C%s %b' \
                   "$bgcolor" "${freqs[i]}" "$strtop" $nl
            strtop=''
        done
        printf '\e[16CLowest: %8.3f Mhz ' $lowest
    done
    echo
}

Will keep lowest and highest frequences:
2011.592 MHz    Top:    3192.718 Mhz 
2000.754 MHz     
...
1999.129 MHz     
1995.587 MHz    Lowest: 1197.234 Mhz 

Hit Any key to exit loop!

CPU Frequency monitor, with bars
Please take the two functions: percent  and percentBar from How to add a progress bar to a shell script?, then you could use this function:
monitCpuFreq() {
    local delay=${1:-0.1} top=0.0 lowest freqs init strtop nl pct bar
    local -i i bgcolor
    local -Ai color='([Rose]=217 [Peach]=209 [BrYellow]=229
                                            [BrGreen]=151 [PaleBlue]=110)'
    while ! read -sn 1 -t $delay _; do
        getCpuFreqs freqs
        (( ${freqs[0]/.} > ${top/.} )) && top=${freqs[0]}
        ! [[ $lowest ]] || (( ${freqs[-1]/.} < ${lowest/.} )) &&
            lowest=${freqs[-1]}
        if ! [[ -n $init ]]; then
            printf '%.0s\n' ${freqs[@]:1}
            printf '\e[%dA\e7' $(( ${#freqs[@]} -1 ))
            init='done'
        fi
        printf '\e8'
        printf -v strtop 'Top:%12.3f Mhz' $top
        for i in ${!freqs[@]}; do
            if (( i == ${#freqs[@]} -1 )); then
                nl='\r\e[12C';printf -v strtop 'Lowest:%9.3f Mhz' $lowest
            else nl=\\n; fi
            percent $(( ${freqs[i]/.}-${lowest/.})) $((${top/.}-${lowest/.})) pct
            percentBar $pct $((${COLUMNS:-80}-35)) bar
            bgcolor=$(( ${freqs[i]/.*} >= 3675 ? color["Rose"] :
                        ${freqs[i]/.*} >= 3275 ? color["Peach"] :
                        ${freqs[i]/.*} >= 2175 ? color["BrYellow"]:${freqs[i]/.*}
                        >= 1975 ? color["BrGreen"] : color["PaleBlue"] ))
            printf '\e[48;5;%dm\e[30m%8.3f MHz\e[0m%22s \e[40;38;5;%dm%s\e[0m%b'\
                   "$bgcolor" "${freqs[i]}" "$strtop" "$bgcolor" "$bar" $nl
            strtop=''
        done
    done
echo ;}

Will show on a my 4 core system, something like:

This accept delay as argument:
monitCpuFreq .25

for 4 refresh / second.
Final version.
With help of Peter Cordes's comment I've found correct values for min and max in: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[:digit:]*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_(min|max)_freq.
About bounds for color selection, I've finally choose to use HSV -> RGB conversion for automatically compute color from min to max -> from blue to red -> from Hue = 240 to 0.

This will permit to use same Hue with different Saturation and Value for bars and background.

In order to simplify cut'n past, I will post all functions here:
#!/bin/bash

percentBar ()  { 
    local prct totlen=$((8*$2)) lastchar barstring blankstring;
    printf -v prct %.2f "$1"
    ((prct=10#${prct/.}*totlen/10000, prct%8)) &&
        printf -v lastchar '\\U258%X' $(( 16 - prct%8 )) ||
            lastchar=''
    printf -v barstring '%*s' $((prct/8)) ''
    printf -v barstring '%b' "${barstring// /\\U2588}$lastchar"
    printf -v blankstring '%*s' $(((totlen-prct)/8)) ''
    printf -v "$3" '%s%s' "$barstring" "$blankstring"
}
percent(){
    if [[ $2 ]] && (( $2 )); then 
        local p=00$(($1*100000/$2))
        printf -v "$3" %.2f ${p::-3}.${p: -3}
    else
        printf -v "$3" %.2f 0
    fi
}

rgb() {
    local -n _result="$4"
    local -i _rgb_i=" (($1%360)/60)%6 "
    local -i _rgb_f=" 100000000*($1%360)/60-_rgb_i*100000000 "
    local _rgb_s; printf -v _rgb_s %.8f "$2"; _rgb_s=$((10#${_rgb_s/.}))
    local -i _rgb_l=" $3*(100000000-_rgb_s)/100000000 "
    case $_rgb_i in
        0 ) local -i _rgb_n="$3*(100000000-(100000000-_rgb_f)*_rgb_s/100000000)/
                                100000000 "
            _result=("$3" "$_rgb_n" "$_rgb_l") ;;
        1 ) local -i _rgb_m=" $3*(100000000-_rgb_f*_rgb_s/100000000)/100000000 "
            _result=("$_rgb_m" "$3" "$_rgb_l") ;;
        2 ) local -i _rgb_n="$3*(100000000-(100000000-_rgb_f)*_rgb_s/100000000)/
                                100000000 "
            _result=("$_rgb_l" "$3" "$_rgb_n") ;;
        3 ) local -i _rgb_m=" $3*(100000000-_rgb_f*_rgb_s/100000000)/100000000 "
            _result=("$_rgb_l" "$_rgb_m" "$3") ;;
        4 ) local -i _rgb_n="$3*(100000000-(100000000-_rgb_f)*_rgb_s/100000000)/
                                100000000 "
            _result=("$_rgb_n" "$_rgb_l" "$3") ;;
        * ) local -i _rgb_m=" $3*(100000000-_rgb_f*_rgb_s/100000000)/100000000 "
            _result=("$3" "$_rgb_l" "$_rgb_m") ;;
    esac
}

getCpuFreqs() {
    local _cF__str  _cF__str2 _cpuInf _cpuId
    mapfile -t _cpuInf < /proc/cpuinfo
    read -ra _cpuInf <<<"${_cpuInf[*]/#!(cpu MHz+($'\t'): *)}"
    local -ai _cF__cpu=("${!_cpuInf[@]}")    
    printf -v _cF__str '[9999999999999999-%s]+="%%s " ' "${_cpuInf[@]/.}"
# shellcheck disable=SC2059  # ( _cF__str is a builded format string )
    printf -v _cF__str2 "$_cF__str" "${_cF__cpu[@]}"
# shellcheck disable=SC2059  # ( _cF__str is a builded format string )
    printf -v _cF__str "$_cF__str" "${_cpuInf[@]}"
    local -a "_cpuInf=($_cF__str)" "_cpuId=($_cF__str2)"
    IFS=\  read -ra "${1:-cpuFreqs}" <<<"${_cpuInf[*]}"
    IFS=\  read -ra "${2:-cpuNums}" <<<"${_cpuId[*]}"
}

monitCpuFreq() {
    if ! shopt -q extglob; then local unsetExtGlob=1; shopt -s extglob; fi
    local delay=${1:-0.25} top=0.0 lowest freqs init strtop nl pct bar
    local -i _mF_i=0 bgcolor fgcolor cHue fMin fMax bgcolor2 cId
    ! [[ -v COLUMNS ]] &&  local COLUMNS && COLUMNS="$(tput cols)"
    while for l in min max; do
              read -r "f${l^}[_mF_i]" \
               </sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$_mF_i/cpufreq/cpuinfo_${l}_freq
          done 2>/dev/null; do
          ((_mF_i++))
    done
    while ! read -rsn 1 -t "$delay" _; do
        getCpuFreqs freqs cId
        (( ${freqs[0]/.} > ${top/.} )) && top=${freqs[0]}
        ! [[ $lowest ]] || ((${freqs[-1]/.}<${lowest/.})) && lowest=${freqs[-1]}
        if ! [[ $init ]]; then
            printf '%.0s\n' "${freqs[@]:1}"
            printf '\e[%dA\e7' $(( ${#freqs[@]} -1 ))
            init='done'
        fi
        printf '\e8'
        printf -v strtop 'Top:%12.3f Mhz' "$top"

        for _mF_i in "${!freqs[@]}"; do
            if (( _mF_i == ${#freqs[@]} -1 )); then
            nl='\r\e[12C';printf -v strtop 'Lowest:%9.3f Mhz' "$lowest"
            else nl=\\n; fi
# shellcheck disable=SC2004  # ${} required for double index ${fMin[cId[_mF_i]]}
            percent $(( ${freqs[_mF_i]/.} - ${fMin[cId[_mF_i]]} < 0 ? 0 :
                    ${freqs[_mF_i]/.} - fMin[${cId[_mF_i]}] )) \
                $(( ${fMax[cId[_mF_i]]} - ${fMin[cId[_mF_i]]} )) pct
            percentBar "$pct" $((${COLUMNS:-80}-35)) bar
            cHue=" ${freqs[_mF_i]/.} < ${fMin[cId[_mF_i]]} ? 240 :
                    ${freqs[_mF_i]/.} > ${fMax[cId[_mF_i]]} ? 0 :
                    240 - ( 5 + 2400 *
                            ( ${freqs[_mF_i]/.} - ${fMin[cId[_mF_i]]} ) /
                            ( fMax[cId[_mF_i]] - fMin[cId[_mF_i]] ) ) / 10 "
            rgb $cHue .7 210 fgcolor
            rgb $cHue .32 240 bgcolor
            bgcolor2=("${bgcolor[@]}")
#            rgb $cHue .6 140 bgcolor2
            printf \
  '\e[30;48;2;%d;%d;%dm%12s\e[0m%22s \e[48;2;%d;%d;%d;38;2;%d;%d;%dm%s\e[0m%b' \
                    "${bgcolor[@]}" "${freqs[_mF_i]} MHz" "$strtop" \
                    "${bgcolor2[@]}" "${fgcolor[@]}" "$bar" "$nl"
            strtop=''
        done
    done
    [[ -v unsetExtGlob ]] && shopt -u extglob
    echo
}
[[ $0 = "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]] && monitCpuFreq "$@"

Still work as a function, but last line will permit to run this as a plain script.
I've augmented default delay to 250 milliseconds, but this could be changed by submitting another delay as argument.
Where backgroud pale colors are same on both side and bar are drawn with dunker and more saturated colors:

Same under xterm:

This become more readable, when  (blue) bar of near 0% are shown.

This works fine. Thanks for sharing your solution!

@Bengt Edited: changed newline at last line in order to prevent blank last line at output.

Added top and lowest values! Nice information!

Ouh, that is a nice feature! Thanks for adding the lowest and highest clocks.

Percent bars added!!!

@Bengt Changed the way of reading /proc/cpuinfo in order to reduce system footprint!

If you are okay with using a script, you can get a color coded list:
#!/bin/bash

clear
while true; do
    line=1
    grep 'MHz' /proc/cpuinfo | awk '{printf "%.0f\n", $4}'\
      | sort -rn | while read freq; do
        if [ "$freq" -ge 3675 ]; then
            bgcolor=217  # Rose (very high)
        elif [ "$freq" -ge 3275 ]; then
            bgcolor=209  # Peach (high)
        elif [ "$freq" -ge 2175 ]; then
            bgcolor=229  # bright yellow (medium)
        elif [ "$freq" -ge 1975 ]; then
            bgcolor=151  # Bright green (medium low)
        else
            bgcolor=110  # Pale blue (low)
        fi
        # Move cursor to correct line and print clock
        printf "\e[%d;1H\e[48;5;%dm\e[30m%4d MHz\e[0m" "$line" "$bgcolor" "$freq"
        ((line++))
    done
    # Move cursor below last line
    printf "\e[%d;1H" "$line"
    sleep 0.1
done



Avoid useless pipe... awk '/^cpu..Hz/{printf "%.3f\n", $4}' </proc/cpuinfo.

As asked by Cyrus's comment you could delete this answer and extend your question! Then leave a comment to @Cyrus and vote to re-open your question.

Could you explain where do you take this bounds (3675, 3275, 2175 and 1975) ??

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub: Relevant thresholds would be near-max boost (Intel calls this "turbo", AMD calls it "boost"), max all-cores-at-once boost or maybe max non-boost (aka base frequency it can sustain on all cores for any workload without exceeding max TDP, i.e. the sticker frequency that's part of the CPUID model string), a lower frequency it downclocks to if 512-bit instructions are in-flight (especially Intel), and a frequency it downclocks to when the workload is memory-bottlenecked.  (e.g. my 4GHz i7-6700k likes to downclock to 2.7GHz doing nothing but huge memcpy.)

@PeterCordes Thanks for your answer, anyway between XEON, AMD64, IA64... all system work significantly differently... My own system use a Corei5@3.20GHz, but I see freqs between 800 and 3700 MHz... (My desktop is not a gammer machine, I don't remember having overclocked them in the bios...). My question was about how to compute this thresholds automatically, based on "cpuinfo" or else...

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub: Yeah, idle (minimum) frequency is usually about 600 to 800 MHz; that's usually the most efficient frequency for energy per work; any slower and you can't lower the voltage any more, and static leakage power starts to be really significant.  IDK how to query at run-time what some of the interesting CPU frequencies are, but base (3.2GHz for yours) and max turbo (3.7 GHz) can be had from the model string and from /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_{min,max}_freq (which differ per-core with E and P cores, and maybe with golden-core turbo 3.0)

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub: So perhaps you'd want to set a "high" threshold a few hundred MHz below the max frequency, or half-way between base freq and max boost?  This is just off the top of my head; I don't like to waste CPU time running programs that constantly display CPU frequency so IDK what people would find useful.  In terms of characterizing workloads, seeing when cores are busy but below base frequency is interesting (to me, since I know it means memory-bound on my Skylake, at least when energy_performance_preference is anything lower than full performance)

To get a nice list of current CPU speeds, you can filter the content of sysfs using grep and order it using sort get an ordered list of your CPU clock speeds using grep
watch 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz | sort -rnk 4'

This creates real-time lists like so:
cpu MHz         : 3729.014
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cpu MHz         : 2199.772
cpu MHz         : 2199.756
cpu MHz         : 2182.517
cpu MHz         : 2109.182


Avoid useless cat! Use: watch 'grep ^cpu..Hz /proc/cpuinfo | sort -rnk 4'
